# use of exception in inheritance

Tags: java

```
class B {
    void process()throws Exception{
        System.out.println("hi sh");
    }

}
class C extends B {
    void process(){
        System.out.println("hhhhhh");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        B a=new C();
        try{
             a.process();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here while calling the process method, we have to use a try catch block.  But, if I store the object of C in reference variable of C only i.e. `C a=new C()` then try catch block is not needed.

Can anyone tell me the reason why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java. Removing throws declaration in overriden method, yet compiler want a try/catch blok when invoking.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413599/java-removing-throws-declaration-in-overriden-method-yet-compiler-want-a-try-c)

Answer (score 5):

The compiler can't (in general) tell which type the variable `a` will have during run-time. Thus, it (always) takes the safe route, and requires you to put `try`/`catch` around the call.

When you do

```
C a = new C();
```

instead, the compiler *can* be sure that `B.process()` is not called at run-time, thus you are allowed to call it without `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment to reference will be done at run time.

And exception declaration checking is done at compile time.

If you write

```
B a=new C();//
```

Here compiler knows that method of a can also be called it is run time decision so it forces us to handle exception.

But if you use

```
C a=new C() ;
```

Compiler is pretty sure that C's method is going to be called so it doesn't declared to throw exception so it allows

Answer (score 0):

Because the signature of `B.process()` is `void process() throws Exception`.

In your `C` class, you've narrowed the signature to `void process()`.

When you declare a reference to be of type `B`, you need to handle the (checked) exception that `B.process()` is declared to throw.

When you declare the reference to be of type `C`, there is no exception that `C.process()` is declared to throw.

When you instantiate an object as `B a = new C()`, then `a` is of *runtime* type `C` but the declaration type is `B`. The compiler treats `a` as a type `B` *because you declared it to be `B`*. This is polymorphism at work.

Answer (score 0):

This only happens with *checked* exceptions and this is due to polymorphism.

In you case C `is-a` B so when you call `process()` you *might* throw a checked exception (the one you **have** to handle).

The safest to handle the exception is forcing the developer to handle this exception whenever `process()` is called on *a* B (which could also be a C but you don't know that before runtime).

Answer (score 0):

> here while calling the process method
>   we have to use a try catch block but
>   if i store the object of C in
>   reference variable of C only i.e. C
>   a=new C() then try catch block is not
>   needed.Can anyone tell me the reason
>   why?

You need to keep in mind that the `run-time` type of a reference is not necessarily the same as the `declared` type. For example:

```
Number n = new Integer(1);
```

This declares n to be a reference of *declared type* `java.lang.Number` to **reference** a subclass of `java.lang.Number` of specific class/type `java.lang.Integer`.

Information about the *actual* **run-time** type is (typically) only available at run-time. But the compiler only operates at compile time. At compile time, the compiler (typically) only knows about the **declared** types.

Since it typically only knows about **declared** types, it can only go with that for making decisions on what can compile and what cannot. That is, javac can only enforce rules based on what it knows (or can infer) at compile time.

Going back to your code example:

The compiler is looking at the *declared* type of the reference (in this case the reference `a` is of type `B`). Based on that, the compiler knows that the method `B.process()` throws a checked exception that it needs to enforce.

That is, either

```
B a=new C();
```

or

```
B a=new B();
```

declare `a` of being of type `B` whose `process()` method throws a checked exception. However, if you have the following:

```
C a = new C();
```

then, the *declared* type of a is `C`, not `B`. Since subclasses can *weaken* the preconditions of its inherited methods, then `C` is free to weaken the preconditions of `process()`. Namely, it can declare `C.process()` to throw a subset of the set of exceptions thrown by `B.process` (and in C.process() case, it is the null set.)

This is somewhat related to the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract), with the former (thanks wikipedia) stating the following principles (3 and 4 being directly related to what you observed in your java code):

> 1. Contravariance of method arguments in the subtype.
> 2. Covariance of return types in the subtype.
> 3. No new exceptions should be thrown by methods of the subtype, except
>      where those exceptions are themselves
>      subtypes of exceptions thrown by the
>      methods of the supertype.
> 4. Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype.
> 5. Postconditions cannot be weakened in a subtype.
> 6. Invariants of the supertype must be preserved in a subtype.

The Java compiler is simply attempting to enforce some of these principles, and by practical purposes, it uses the *declared* types of reference variables to determine **how** to enforce them.

Answer (score 0):

When we write :

```
B a=new C();
```

we are implicitly type casting object of C to object B.

```
a.process();
```

in Run time it will call process() of C but while compiling, for compiler a is still the object of B and as B has process() throwing exception so it must be catch using try/catch.

if we use :

```
C a = new C();
a.process();
```

while compiling, for compiler a is still the object of C (and may contain reference to other subclass object) and as C's has process() is not throwing any exception so NO NEED to catch using try/catch.