# Removing throws in overriden method, compiler wants a try/catch block when invoking

Tags: java

I have a subclass and I am overriding the inherited parent method: I am removing the throws clause from the method declaration.

Now, using polymorphism, the my instance's runtime type should determine the method implementation; yet, the compiler complains and wants a try/catch block around the method invocation when I try to compile, as if the superclass method is being invoked and not the subclass version?

I'm aware that I can remove the throws declaration or narrow down the checked exception which can be thrown when overriding. Why is this still throwing the exception?

```
class A{
    void foo()throws Exception{throw new Exception();}
}    

class SubB extends A{
    @Override
    void foo(){  System.out.println("B");  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new SubB();
    a.foo(); //compiler reports: unhandled exception type Exception 
}
```

Comment: It's working exactly as it should.  The `foo` method of `A` can throw an `Exception`, so you need to catch it, since `main` is not marked to throw `Exception`.  It does not matter that `a` is actually a `SubB` -- what matters is how `a` is declared.

Comment: You can have main() throws Exception otherwise you need `SubB a` as `A.foo()` throws an Exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler ses an `A` which *does* throw an Exception. If you however told the compiler it's an actual `SubB` object it will stop complaining

```
SubB b = new SubB();
b.foo();
```

Comment: Ok, then.  At runtime it will behave as expected via polymorphism, but at compile time its seen as A instance and thus requires a appropriate try/catch block. Thanks to everyone who responded!

Comment: @Mandark -- It's not just compile time.  Any runtime use of the variable `a` will assume it's an instance of `A`, and if you, eg, assign it to a `SubB` you must do a cast, and the cast will actually be checked at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

That has happened because assigning the `SubB` instance to `a` removes the knowledge that the instance is a `SubB`.  As an `A`, `a.foo()` can now (as far as the JLS is concerned) throw `Exception`.

Compile-time type knowledge is based on the declared types of the variables rather than any (hypothetical) inferred types if the variable contents.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is right.  The line

`A a = new SubB();`

"Means "create instance of class `SubB` and assign it to variable of type `A`".

This means that from this point the variable `a`'s type is `A`, not `SubB`. But `foo()` defined in `A` throws unchecked Exception that must be re-thrown or caught by caller. This is what compiler tells you.

At line 
`a.foo()`
compiler already "does not know" that the real instance type is `SubB`. It treats it as `A`.

Comment: Why I'm confusing it with polymorphism a.k.a reference type determines which method may be called, and the runtime instance type determines implementation?